# Why does Rails say "cannot load such file mysql/mysql_api"?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was following a tutorial on [lynda.com (RoR 3: Section 6, ep. 3)](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Ruby-Rails-3-Essential-Training/55960-2.html) and after installing MySQL and running:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

I got:

```
rake aborted! cannot load such file mysql/mysql_api
C:/Sites/demo/config/application.rb:7:in '<top <required>>'
C:/Sites/demo/Rakefile:4:in 'require'
C:/Sites/demo/Rakefile:4:in '<top <required>>'
```

I did copy:

```
libmySQL.dll
```

To:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin
```

and I also tried uninstalling and installing the `mysql` gem a couple of times.

Comment: Have you tried the mysql2 gem? The old one is for Ruby 1.8 AFAIK

Comment: I've tried installing gem 'mysql2', but I get an error: Failed to build gem native extension. At the end there is: Make sure that 'gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'' succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Ah a common error on Windows. RailsInstaller should've taken care of the Devtools. I'm not developing on Windows anymore because of the problems, so I cannot help you directly, but please have a look at this: http://rubylearning.com/blog/how-do-i-install-a-ruby-gem-with-native-extensions-on-windows/

Comment: Nothing helped. Can I still use 'mysql' and make it work? How to solve error in the title?

Comment: No I think you cannot use the old 'mysql' gem with Ruby 1.9. In any case, you need to fix your Devtool problem or you will soon be getting the very same error messages when installing other gems.

Comment: Really, use Linux (or Mac) if you want to develop seriously with Rails.

Comment: @Pigueiras funny thing is that Rails is hard to install even on Linux (Ubuntu). Having a hard time trying to install it.

Comment: @renocor Follow the instructions here to install rvm: http://rvm.io/rvm/install and then `gem install rails`. Why is it difficult?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is similar to [cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693908/cannot-load-such-file-mysql-mysql-api/20727172#20727172).

If you are trying to access 64 bit MySQL from 32 bit Ruby then you might encounter this.