# cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am completing the tutorial on *Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training* through Lynda.com on *Windows 7*, and I am in the section on "Databases and Migrations". I am attempting to sync the database I have created in MySQL with my Rails project, however I have been running into an abort message. The instructor asked my class to go through Command Prompt to open up our rails project and perform a Rake to build a "schema.rb" with this code:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Yet each time I type the code in I have gotten this error message:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\simple_cms>rake db:schema:dump

rake aborted!

cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api

C:/Users/User/Documents/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

C:/Users/User/Documents/simple_cms/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Some solutions I have attempted:**

1. I have installed the binary version of mysql. It was built using *MySQL Connector/C version 6.0.2*. and I added

   libmySQL.dll

to

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin
```

from dev.mysql.com

1. I have attempted to download the "mysql2" Gem through Command Prompt with the following result:

   ```
   C:\Users\User\Documents\simple_cms>gem install mysql2

   Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...

   Building native extensions.  This could take a while..

   ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:

   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   ```

Help?

Comment: try `gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin`

Comment: @JustinWood Thanks for the response! So I just pasted your code in to Command however this was the result: ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Where did you install MySQL? replace the directory in that command with wherever it was installed. If that does not work, try checking out the [readme](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) on the github page.

Comment: @JustinWood Thanks again. I read the readme and followed the instructions under Windows clinically yet when I typed in "gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.2-winx64" I got that error message once more "ERROR: Error installing mysql2"

Comment: Justin Wood's suggestion worked for me on Ruby2.2.0

Answer (score 4):

Or just instalo mysql2 gem. It Works for me at Wim 10.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to access a 64 bit MySQL installation from 32 bit Ruby installation. This seems to be problem with a lot of ppl, even I encountered this when I had a new Win7(64 bit) new machine.

try the solution provided on this blog :-

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

Comment: Thanks @DKS I followed these instruction and the result changed the error message I receive:This is what it says now when I run "db:schema:dump"

C:\Sites\todo>rake db:schema:dump rake aborted! You have already activated rake 10.1.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.3. U sing bundle exec may solve this. C:/Sites/todo/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>' C:/Sites/todo/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' C:/Sites/todo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>' (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: I hope you tried bundle exec or install as mentioned in the error message. Also, it looks you have rake version 10.1.1 installed, while required is 10.0.3. You can remove it by doing :
gem list rake
 and then gem uninstall rake -v 10.1.1

do bundle install/exec after this and I hope your problem should get resolved.