# How to resolve loaderror in ROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anybody please help me to resolve this error.I am tring to work with mysql and ROR

- modified the gem file as "gem mysql" and database.yml file
- copied the libmysql.dll(from mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-winx64 folder) file to rubu193/bin folder.
- typed gem install mysql and it installed succefully.
- typed bundle install

  but when i typed rake db:create,it gave the following error.

Error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api
c:/Site/book/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Site/book/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

please help to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you run bundle install?

Comment: yes,i have done bundle install after that i typed rake db:create and i got the above error.

Comment: Try `bundle exec rake db:create`

Comment: Hello,Boris as per you,i typed that command,but same error which has shown above also displayed.

Comment: @subhra Have a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693908/cannot-load-such-file-mysql-mysql-api). Maybe that solves your issues.