# How to resolve load error in ROR-4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

plase any can help me to resolve this error.after typing gem install mysql,i typed bundle install.
when i typed command rake db:create/bundle exec rake db:create it gave the following error.

Error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api
c:/Site/book/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Site/book/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Sqldb
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

My rakefile contains the following codes.

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve loaderror in ROR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545612/how-to-resolve-loaderror-in-ror)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access a 64 bit MySQL installation from 32 bit Ruby installation. This seems to be problem with a lot of ppl, even I encountered this when I had a new Win7(64 bit) new machine.

try the solution provided on this blog :-

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/